# Oasis vs Oases - Which to use?

Tags: grammatical-number, phrasing

I am looking over something before posting it online and I have a sentence that simply doesn't seem to 'sound' right either way I write it. Specifically, I am trying to decide whether it is more correct to use 'oasis' or 'oases' in the sentence below.

There are two types of [oasis/oases] in the world.

If it makes a difference, these are metaphorical oases.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This arises with any word; _There are two types of mountain/banana/book in the world_ versus _There are two types of mountains/bananas/books in the world_. Both are correct, singular or plural; there is no difference in meaning. Just speaker's choice, like most such choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural of **oasis** is **oases**, which you should use if you have more than one:

> There are two types of oases in the world.

But if that doesn't sound right to you, make it singular:

> There is more than one type of oasis in the world.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> This arises with any word; *There are two types of mountain/banana/book in the world* versus *There are two types of mountains/bananas/books in the world*. Both are correct, singular or plural; there is no difference in meaning. Just speaker's choice, like most such choices.